# Unable to add a jar as a library in Visual Studio Code Java Extension pack

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Im trying to add json.jar to the current workspace, When i try to add, it shows me my file explorer (nautilus in my case) but im unable to click on anything like it was "disabled"

[image]

[image]

as you can see, i can't click on it, i also tried to do it from settings.json:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "/home/user1/tests/json.jar"
]
```

and reloading vscode and the result still the same, libraries list still empty, i tried to compile a .java file with json.jar to check if the problem is from the jar file itself but it worked withtout problems.

```
javac -cp json.jar test.java
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like a issue, as this page mentioned:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/issues/238.